# Laravel Eloquent complex query building

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have trouble to achieve my goal to build a filterable complex query.

I have 5 tables. One of them is a time tracking table. To keep that global, I just store the `item_id` and the `time_categories_id` to recognize which item it is.
I also need some additional information which is not directly in relation, so for example, I need the client informations which are assigned to a task.

So I have following tables (in short form listed):

```
times
--------------------------------------------------------
| id | name | description | item_id | time_category_id |
--------------------------------------------------------

time_categories
-------------
| id | name |
-------------

clients
------------------------------------
| id | company| name | description | 
------------------------------------

(client has many projects and projects may have many clients)

projects
------------------------------------
| id | company| name | description | 
------------------------------------

tasks
----------------------------------------
| id | name | description | project_id |
----------------------------------------

tickets
------------------------------------------------
| id | company| name | description | client_id |
------------------------------------------------
```

Now I want to create a filter function in which the return should depend on if client or project id is submitted.

For this filter, I created following query:

```
$timeQuery = Time::select(array(
'times.*',
'time_categories.name as type',
'tasks.name as task_name',
'tasks.description as task_description',
'tickets.name as ticket_name',
'tickets.description as ticket_description'))
->join('time_categories','times.time_category_id','=','time_categories.id')
->leftJoin('tasks',function($join) use ($project){
    if(!empty($project))
    {
        $join->on('times.item_id', '=', 'tasks.id')
        ->where('tasks.project_id','=',$project);
    }else{
        $join->on('times.item_id', '=', 'tasks.id');
    }
})
->leftJoin('tickets',function($join) use ($client){
    if(!empty($client))
    {
        $join->on('times.item_id','=','tickets.id')
            ->where('tasks.project_id','=',$client);
    }else{
        $join->on('times.item_id','=','tickets.id');
    }
});
```

So I ended up here. I don't get an error, but I receive all data instead of filtered data only dependent on client or project id.

Does anyone have an advice?

Comment: Ouhh... If you need client information which assign to task, i think can be done with Eloquent ORM, why dont you use Eloquent ORM instead ? Have you read Laravel Many To Many Relationships ? I think you need `client_project` table since it's many to many relationships, then create model.

Comment: yes i use Eloquent ORM and Laravel's Many To Many Relations as well, but in this case, i don't want to get all time entries and eager load it later. i want to select only the time items which are related.